# Ubuntu server lts 22.04.3 errors && warnings while trying to download samba

Tags: networking, apt, server, upgrade, samba

When I try to download samba with `sudo apt-get install samba` I always get the same errors:

[image: Error and warnings]

I'm very knew to ubuntu and I am following a tutorial to try and make a home server: https://youtu.be/IuRWqzfX1ik

I have tried running other commands like `sudo apt-get update || sudo apt-get upgrade` but `sudo apt-get update` also resolves in errors:

[image: Errors while trying to upgrade]

I have *also* tried changing my dns temporarily but I still always see the same results.

I dont know what to do at this point.

Comment: You need a working network connection when installing packages.

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the text into your question.